# IntentService class not running AsyncTask on main ui thread. Method execute must be called from the main thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a weird problem that occurred recently. I am calling a service named NotificationService which extends IntentService class. Now inside the onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method i making call to an async task. The code is given below:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    defPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    //int fiveMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    //Setting an alarm to call AlarmScheduler service now. This alarm scheduler service will set next days alarm to show notifications
    //based on the weekly schedule as obtained from server.
    Intent i = new Intent(NotificationService.this, ScheduleAlarms.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(NotificationService.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) NotificationService.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);//Use AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY instead of int number here.

    //Check if locally notifications are enabled by the user then only show notification depending on
    //if there are any latest notifications to be shown.
    if(defPrefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.notifications),true)) {
        NotificationAsyncTask httpAsyncTask1 = new NotificationAsyncTask();
        httpAsyncTask1.mOnHttpResponseListener = new GetHomeResponse(intent);
        httpAsyncTask1.execute("http://" + HttpAsyncTask.IP_ADDRESS + "/v5/getResult");
    }else{
        Log.v("NotificationService","Disabled");
    }

}
```

Where NotificationAsyncTask is a private class defined inside this service. Now i am getting the error
Method execute must be called from the main thread, currently inferred thread is worker..
I don't understand how this execute method is not running on the main thread? Please help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Now inside the onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method i making call to an async task

`onHandleIntent()` is called on a background thread.

You cannot execute an `AsyncTask` from a background thread.

More importantly, you do not need an `AsyncTask`. Just take your `doInBackground()` code and put it in `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: Yes right, I don't need AsyncTask..didn't give it a thought earlier.Thanks for the hint. Also one more thing in my notifications i only want to show large icon, so how can i disable the small icon as setting small icon is mandatory(using .setSmallIcon() on the NotificationCompat.Builder instance)?

Comment: Also the async task was getting executed though the execute statement was underlined in red color..

Comment: @FingerSmith: "Also one more thing in my notifications i only want to show large icon" -- you would have to build your own mobile operating system. The small icon is what appears in the status bar, and its presence is non-negotiable.

Comment: Actually when I use both small and large icons then the small one when viewed in notifications drawer doesn't get rendered properly, only a small blank grey square is seen, though i see it clealy in the status bar..can you suggest what the problem could be?

Comment: @FingerSmith: "then the small one when viewed in notifications drawer doesn't get rendered properly" -- that should be showing the large icon, so I have no idea what you may be experiencing. Post a separate Stack Overflow question where you show your code and a screenshot of your results.

Comment: What if my Async Task may be called from outside too? In that case should I duplicate the code? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Dpedrinha: "In that case should I duplicate the code?" -- no. You put the code in a common location (e.g., Java class) that can be accessed by both the `AsyncTask` and the `IntentService`.

Comment: I tried putting code in a Util java class that can be accessed by the `AsyncTask` and the `IntentService`, but I ended up getting the error `Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.`